# Sorting Column in SSRS by Background Color

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

Is it possible to sort a column in SSRS by background color? For example, if I have an expression that will make the cell either RED or GREEN, is there a way to have all the columns with RED background cell colour sorted before listing cells which have GREEN as the background cell?

Thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to have alternating background cell colours I would have said that. Actually there would have been 50 hits on google from a quick search so I wouldnt have even asked the question here...  So what are you trying to say.

Comment: As far as sort goes, that's effectively independent of decorations. You can change the sort of your data without applying any color at all. The rules by which you are going to apply color are the same as those that you are going to set `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It makes complete sense. I have background cells colors either GREEN or RED based on an expression. I want all of those that are RED at the top of the report before the GREEN cells.

Comment: You may want to do a screen grab of what you're currently seeing. Open that in paint, and draw a bunch of arrows of how you expected the data to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you Lynn Crumbling. At least you understood what I was asking. And it makes sense that its independent of decor. I just wanted to verify. Thanks.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling make your comment an answer and i will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do this. The only thing I could think of is referring to [`ReportItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx) in the sort expression, but that causes scoping issues (you would get a build error in VStudio), because the sorting is done on the tablix and the background of cells is done one level lower.

However, most likely, your background color expression is either static (does not refer to data), or depends on data. You can use the exact same expression for sorting too. So say you have this for background:

```
=Iif(Fields!Nr.Value > 10, "#FF0000", "#00FF00")
```

You could equally well sort the tablix by:

```
=Iif(Fields!Nr.Value > 10, 1, 0)
```

Or of course sort in SQL already:

```
ORDER BY Nr
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had no idea you could replace the colors with 1 and 0 for sorting!

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I'd much rather see something like this accepted :)